# How can I change vlc tooltip font size?

Tags: gnome, vlc, qt5, tooltip

When I mouse over the time bar in VLC, a tooltip is displayed indicating the hovered over video time. For me, this tooltip is very small, and hard to view unless moving closer to the screen.

Adjusting the font sizes in my current theme (Adwaita) doesn't appear to fix this problem, which I initially believed was associated with Gtk 2.0 theme configuration.

I am currently using the Gnome desktop, version 3.20, but I have experienced this issue in other desktops (Unity, Cinnamon, etc.) as well.

I have included a screenshot to describe my issue.

[image: VLC Tooltip Problem]

Comment: Are you sure your version of vlc is gtk2? Mine isn't. It uses qt, AFAICT.

Comment: @DKBose VLC is a qt app, but it can use the gtk theme I have installed because of the libqt5libqgtk2 package.

Comment: Would an answer that works for regular gtk2 applications such as Geany be acceptable? I installed the package you mentioned and then tried several gtk2 themes but the tooltip you highlight doesn't change with any of them. I wonder if that's hard-coded in VLC.

Comment: @DKBose I think it could be coded into VLC for Linux, but I'm uncertain of that as their is no setting or info in its config files, from what I can tell, that changes the tooltip size. I have noticed the font changed before when using a system theme, so that's why I believe its affected by the system theme configuration.

Comment: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skineditor.html

Comment: This is a qt5 related issue, I'm still having it, trying options in qt5 config is a workaround, but doesn't completely solve this issue.